# coveralls.io and error handling in Golang

Tags: go, error-handling

I wrote a [library for Instagram API](https://github.com/ahmdrz/goinsta) and tell coveralls.io to check my repository

but coveralls.io tell me that all of the error handlers in my source code isn't Good. [see this](https://coveralls.io/builds/8405457/source?filename=request.go)

How can I handle errors perfectly and coveralls.io say it's good :smile:

> sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I think it's trying to tell you that your tests are not covering that path. It means that the tests you wrote are probably testing only the "happy path" and not going into those error handling branches.

Comment: Yeah , So what can I do to get better result from coveralls.io

Comment: It's not about getting "better result". Coveralls is just telling you that your tests are not covering some scenarios, giving you 81% of the coverage, that means that the 19% missing is represented by those red highlighted lines. An example of what you could do is writing a test that calls the `sendRequest` function with the `login` parameter as `false` and then you verify that you're getting back the expected `error`.